# Why won't the code I put in notepad document display on web browser?

Tags: notepad

A month ago I was having trouble saving a notepad document as .allfiles so I could see the code I entered as it would appear on a webpage. Now I can get it to save as .allfiles, but this code is still not coming up right. I can't see what's wrong with it.

heading

paragraph

Comment: We can't see what's wrong with it either. Maybe you could post it here, that would help, yes? :-)

Comment: paxdiablo, thanks. As it turns out it was a stupid mistake and I can't post any more questions for 2 days. Oh well. :)